# Determine file owner from a Windows kernel-mode driver

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Using C in a Windows in a Kernel Mode Driver using KMDF, how do I determine the owner a of file?

I searched high and low but could not find any hint. Only C++ and of course Csharp.

Comment: That'd be in the Windows API somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After opening a handle to a file, you can use the kernel-mode [`ZwQuerySecurityObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the owner information (and full DACL).

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you also tell me where did you learned that? I am trying to develop a pretty simple driver that will mimic behavior of AppLocker but with additional rules, and I find it pretty hard to get related materials. Are there any good books on KMDF development, or Kernel mode development in general? I already own MS Windows Driver Model 2nd edition, by Walter Oney.

Comment: I looked at the implementation of the user-mode `GetFileSecurity` function in IDA to see what NT system call it invoked.